# Магия при создании строк в Java

Tags: строки, java

Совсем недавно увидел такой кусок кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello";
    String s2 = "Hello";
    String s3 = s1;

    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    System.out.println(s3.equals(s1));
}
```

Со третьей строкой всё понятно - выведет **true**. Но каково было моё удивление, когда и первая и вторая выдала **true**!

Кто-нибудь может обьяснить почему? Есть какая-то магия при создании строк в Java?

Comment: Зачем минусуете? Нормальный вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

А почему вас это удивило? Ведь в любой книге по Java в самом начале рассматривается сравнение объектов при помощи `==` и `equals`. Метод `equals` сравнивает объекты по содержимому (если он правильно переопределён; а в классе `String` он переопределён правильно), поэтому две строки, содержащие `"Hello"`, при сравнении через `equals` вернут `true`.

Гораздо интереснее такая ситуация:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = s1;
String s4 = new String("Hello");
String s5 = s4;

System.out.println(s1 == s2);        // true
System.out.println(s3 == s1);        // true
System.out.println(s1 == s4);        // false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s4));   // true
System.out.println(s4 == s5);        // true
```

Обычно оператор `==` в Java сравнивает ссылки и возвращает `true`, только если обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Однако для строковых литералов сделано исключение. Если вы создаёте строку не как новый объект (`String s = new String("Hello");`), а как литерал (`String s = "Hello"`), то такая строка помещается в пул литералов. Если вы создадите ещё одну строку-литерал `"Hello"`, то Java попытается найти такую строку в пуле, и если найдёт, то не будет создавать новую строку, а вернёт ссылку на существующую.

Но не стоит целиком и полностью полагаться на эту "магию". Если строковые литералы, созданные в одной jar-ке гарантированно попадают в один пул, то для литералов из разных jar-ок этого никто не гарантирует (актуально при подключении сторонних библиотек). Поэтому всегда сравнивайте строки (да и вообще все объекты, кроме обёрток примитивных типов) через `equals`.